# PHP - Use multiple class with a single import?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I have multiple classes like: SearchForX, SearchForY, ...

Each class has a search method, so to use them all i need to:

```
use SearchForX;
use SearchForY;
// (...)
```

And in code:

```
$searchForX = SearchForX();
$searchForX->search($input);
$searchForY = SearchForY();
$searchForY->search($input);
// (...)
```

**Is it possible to do something like this:**

```
$search->x($input);

$search->y($input);
```

And have the multiple classes as I said before?

Comment: Yep, you could make a wrapper class for it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix can you share/post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

```
  class SearchWrapper{
        protected $ClassX;
        protected $ClassY;

        public function _construct(){
             $this->ClassX = new ClassX;
             $this->ClassY = new ClassY;
        }

        public function search( $class, $input ){
              $this->{$class}->search($input);
        }
  }
```

Then if you were to go

```
   $S = new SearchWrapper();
   $S->search('ClassY',$input);
   $S->search('ClassX',$input);
```

For example, or something similar.  You see the searchwrapper in this example wraps the functionality of both class x an y